# How can I make 2 relationships between the 'games' and 'users' tables, one for 'wishlist' and one for 'library'?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, mariadb

I'm working on a project for class and I want to relate the users and games tables to create a wishlist and a list of video games called library. Is it possible to create 2 many-to-many relationships between the same 2 tables?

By now, I have them related in a way that shows me two tables in between, but I'm not sure if it would be the correct solution

Comment: It seems like you could use the same relationship between tables and just query them differently for the two functions

Comment: Two relation tables sounds like the correct way to go.

Answer (score -2):

on my point of view is possible, because you can have the same game on several wishlist ( the same game on different users), simplifying in these situation you can have many games linked to many users and many users linked to many games.

You could create a table for wish list, which would have an id_user and id_games, and so you would have a what games is on wishlist of each user.
Like this:

table WISHLIST

| ID_USER | ID_GAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |

table USER

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PETER |

table GAME

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FORTNITE |
| 2 | MINECRAFT |

But you can you show the table you mentioned?

Comment: But could we have a separate library table linked to users and video games, apart from the wishlist?

Comment: On my point of view yes, but can be impracticable if you have two tables for linked users and video games, because the wishlist already do this